# property 'logout' of undefined at HeaderComponent.logout2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I want to implement one logout function across the entire project. I have done  that in the Dashboard component and the logout is fine at that, now I am trying to re-use the function in header, I am getting error at the console - **property 'logout' of undefined
    at HeaderComponent.logout2**

BELOW IS THE SNIPPET OF THE HEADER COMPONENT

```
import { DashboardComponent } from '../dashboard/dashboard.component';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

  @ViewChild(DashboardComponent, {static: false})
  private dash: DashboardComponent;

 logout2() { // this method is undefined, but it exits in dashboard
    this.dash.logout();
  }
```

//here is the dashboard component snippet

```
logout() {
    this.token.signOut();
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
    window.location.reload();
  }
```

To ensure to me that I am on the right track, I have checked angular documentation and arrived at this [https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild](http://angular%20documentation%20here)

I need to solve this error

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz? or try: change to `private` to `public`

Comment: I think the problem is to do with the @ViewChild – clearly it's not picking up the dashboard. Is the DashboardComponent definitely a child of the headerComponent? If not, you'll have to find a different way to give the header access to the dashboard component. To check you have it, just do `console.log(dash)` in the `ngOnInit()` function of your header

Comment: If you wish to share common functionality like this I **highly** recommend using a service.

Comment: Do u have a service answer